# Datatable Editor 1.4 on JQUERY: async AJAX call. How I can to place after?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, asynchronous, datatable, editor

On index.html I have two pages JQM v.1.4.

In page-1 I´ve a form that get  (nombreUsuario) and password and assign  into respective vars.

In page-2 , I want to use the  previous  (nombreUsuario)  for to get table that match with this nombeUsuario via AJAX on  Datatable Editor 1.4.

My problem is that in page-1 the AJAX call is executed  before that  I enter   nombreUsuario , therefore when pass to page-2 the table is empty , due the AJAX call was executed with variable  empty ,  without nombreUsuario entry.

I´ve  tried different code  to get that  AJAX call executed after entry nombreUsuario but I don’t get desired result .  I´ve used  async to false, but to do nothing .

Also,  DataTable Editor AJAX document said : 
Success: Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables . Even so, I´ve used this option  (taking jquery examples) and is true that  don’t work (is yes, please tell me!) .

Now,  will be more easy resolve it  on JQM?. How can I to  get nombreUsuario on page-1 and after pass to page-2 , then will execute AJAX call  with this variable?

Any idea?. Thank you in advance!

index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page0">

<form id="formulario" >
        <label> Usuario </label>
        <input type="text" id="nombredeusuario" name="nombredeusuario">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="clave" name="clave" >
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="botonLogin">
</form> 

...

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Establecimiento</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Nº de Plazas</th>
                <th>Precio medio</th>
                <th>E-mail (responsable)</th>
                <th>Prueba (1) / Contrato (2)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
....
```

JS:
(form)

```
$('#formulario').submit(function() { 
    // recolecta los valores que inserta el usuario
    var datosUsuario = $("#nombredeusuario").val()
    var datosPassword = $("#clave").val()
...
```

JS (datatable editor 1.4)

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
                    //check. start
                        initComplete: function(settings, json) {
                        alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
                            },
                    //check.end
                    dom: "Tfrtip",
                    ajax: {
                        async: false, // don't work
                        url:"http://tripntry.com/_country/spain/b.cartasconmenu.front.back.demo/alacarte/php/clientes.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: function ( d ) {
                             d.site = $("#nombredeusuario").val(); // dont work!
                             //d.site = datosUsuario; //// dont work!
                             //d.site = "34280001"; // works (of course)
                        },
....
```

PHP (server side)

```
include( "../../php/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Join,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;


$site=$_POST['site']; 

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'clientes' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'tipo' )->validator( 'Validate::numeric' ), //this field another use
        Field::inst( 'site' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' )
        )
        ->where( 'site', $site)

    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

Comment: Can you just call $('#example').DataTable( {... on the pagecreate or pagebeforeshow event of page-2?

Comment: Unfortunately not be possible, $('#example').DataTable( ...) , in your API don't consider that you can to use pagecreate or pagebeforeshow. Thank you @ezanker for your comment!